# AppleScript Syntax a real number can't go after this real number?

Tags: syntax, applescript, syntax-error, applescript-objc

I have the following line in an AppleScript project:

```
set script_path to "/tmp/usbmuxd-1.0.7/python-client"
```

When I try to compile, it highlights the `1.0.7` and gives up this message:

[image]

What does this mean?

Comment: which MacOS version are you using?  is python-client a file or a directory?

Comment: `python-client` was a folder. The installation of OSX is 10.9 that I am using. It was a syntax error from above this particular line of code.

Answer (score 2):

The code surrounding this one line did not have a `"` mark where it was required. Thus causing the error.

I checked the code manually and could not see the error after your comment, so I re-wrote the entire code this line comes from, and it worked too!

So I compared the code between the two files and found that simply it was a single quotation that was missing from a dialog box above by a few lines causing the issue.